# A question about locally compact spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness

Recently I read a book about linear algebraic group written by Ian Macdonald. There is a conclusion which I can't prove.

It says that if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space, then $X$ is compact if and only if, for all locally compact spaces $Y$, the projection $X\times Y \to Y$ is a closed map. Is it a fact for all topology spaces?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess that has to do with the [properness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) of $X \times Y \to Y$?

Comment: This seems to be a bit similar question to this one: ["Kuratowski-Mrówka theorem" Need reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2740203) This question only asks about one implication, but some of the answers mention that it is in fact a characterization: [Projection map being a closed map](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22697).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can find this in Engelking's *General Topology* as Theorem 3.1.16 (for Hausdorff spaces but it works in general).

See also [*Compactness and product spaces*, Coll. Math., 7 (1959), 19--22](https://eudml.org/doc/210657) by S. Mrowka.

See Problem 3.12.1 in Engelking's book for the following: if $X$ is not compact then there is a sequence $\langle F_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ of nonempty closed sets that is decreasing ($\alpha<\beta$ imlies $F_\alpha\supseteq F_\beta$) and has an empty intersection. In addition we assume that when $\alpha$ is a limit then $F_\alpha=\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}F_\beta$. Then $\{\langle\alpha,x\rangle:x\in F_\alpha\}$ is a closed subset of $(\kappa+1)\times X$ (where $\kappa+1$ has the order topology and so is compact), whose projection along $X$ is the set $\kappa$ and hance not closed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't know how to prove that X is compact when the projection is a closed map for any locally compact spaces Y

Comment: I think you meant Theorem 3.1.16 rather than 3.1.6

Comment: Right, 3.1.16, fixed it.

Comment: @Fuutorider See the answer below; or my answer for another construction, which works without assumptions on separartion axioms.

Comment: @NikWeaver What would be the closed set with non-closed projection? The diagonal is definitely not closed: every non-empty open rectangle $U\times Y$ intersects it, so $X\times\{\infty\}$ is in its closure. And: the diagonal could even be dense in $X\times X$ (in a very non-Hausdorff space).

Comment: Oh, you're right, I retract my comment.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ isn't compact, let $Y$ be its one point compactification (or any compactification, really) and consider the set $\{(x,x): x\in X\}$. It's closed in $X\times Y$, but its projection into $Y$, namely $X\subset Y$, is not.

Comment: As KP Hart points out, this solution assumes $X$ is Hausdorff.